# Remote connection to MSSQL 2012 is working but not from Local server

Tags: python, sql-server-2012, pyodbc

I have created a python 3.7.2 script to connect with MSSQL 2012 R2 Datacenter, I am able to connect with db from Remote that's from my Laptop and fetch the data in the table and saving it as xxxxx.xlsx file using pandas, I am using pyodbc for DB connection.
Now I have converted .py files into one .exe file using pyinstaller, when I run the .exe file in the server where I have the installed the Database server I am not seeing the xxxxx.xlsx file in folder.

I tried server name, server ip address and localhost, but no success

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from pwd_cfg import db_password, sql_server, mit_database, user, db_driver

def sql_connect():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={%s};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (db_driver, sql_server, mit_database, user, db_password))
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT SalesorderType FROM MIT.dbo.MitInputs WHERE Status = 'Active'")

    rows = []
    for row in cursor:
        rows.append(row)
    x = (rows[0][0])
    xx = x.split(',')
    xxx = [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in xx]

    df = pd.DataFrame(xxx)
    df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\jacobl\PythonProjects\MIT_Project\TempDir\SalesorderType.xlsx")

    cursor.close()
sql_connect()
```

select statement should run and it should be saved in the .xlsx file for the next process to use the .xlsx file

Comment: Are you logging any errors that might arise when your code runs? Is the ODBC driver installed on the server? Does the path to which you are trying save the .xlsx file actually exist on the server?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in exception, I tried print('xxxx') after xxx= and df.to_excel statements I see the print statement is printed in the cmd console. The script should create the .xlsx in the path based on the select statement result.

Comment: Gord Thompson one more information I see the .xlsx file is getting created in the TempDir folder but after the cursor.close() the .xlsx file is getting removed/deleted automatically that's why I get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\HP.MIT.TEST\\TEMPDIR\\SalesorderType.xlsx'